Using newer SAPI voices in Delphi app (e.g. Microsoft Mark)
My company has a Delphi app that has been using SAPI to render wav files for over 20 years; recently, a customer asked why our voice selection list only has Microsoft Mike and Microsoft Zira when the Windows Speech settings indicate Microsoft Mark is available; after some reading I learned that the old way of enumerating the voices does not pick up the newer voices.
Currently, our app uses:
Speech := CreateOLEObject('SAPI.SPVOICE') as ISpeechVoice;
VoiceTokens := Speech.GetVoices('', '');

From what I've read online, this accesses the old-school SAPI, not the new-and-improved stuff.
I've gone round-and-round with Bing Copilot and it has confidently suggested a lot of stuff that does not work.
So far I have created a new SpeechLib_TLB.pas unit using TLibImp.exe to export on C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\common\sapi_onecore.dll
(I'm running Windows 10)
Following the suggestions from Bing Copilot I have come up with the following voice enumeration procedure:
procedure TMainForm.EnumerateVoices;
Const
  SPCAT_VOICES = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens';
var
  Voice: ISpVoice;
  Category: ISpObjectTokenCategory;
  EnumTokens: IEnumSpObjectTokens;
  Token: ISpObjectToken;
  TokenCount: Cardinal;
  TokenID: PWideChar;
  EnumResult: HResult;
begin
Try
  ListBox.Clear;
  Voice := CoSpVoice.Create; // Create an instance of the SpVoice object
  Category := CoSpObjectTokenCategory.Create;
  if Succeeded(Category.SetId(SPCAT_VOICES, 0))
    then
      if Succeeded(Category.EnumTokens(nil, nil, EnumTokens))
        then
          begin
          EnumResult := EnumTokens.Next(1, Token, TokenCount);
          while EnumResult = S_OK do
            begin
            Token.GetId(TokenID);
            ListBox.Items.Add(TokenID);
            Token := nil;
            EnumResult := EnumTokens.Next(1, Token, TokenCount);
            end;
          end
        Else
          ShowMessage('Category.EnumTokens failed')
    Else
      ShowMessage('Category.SetId failed');
  Voice := nil;
  ShowMessage('EnumerateVoices found '+ListBox.Count.ToString+' voices');
  Except
    On E:Exception do ShowMessage('EnumerateVoices failed. Error: '+E.Message);
  End;
end;

Unfortunately, the first call to EnumToken.Next returns 0x00000001 (S_FALSE)
Since the A.I. regurgitators have let me down, can any Authentic Intelligence Gurus help me out?

I don't have experience working with SAPI but looking at ISpObjectTokenCategory documentation shouldn't you call Category.SetId(SPCAT_VOICES, TRUE) so that category interface is created if it doesn't exists yet. Also why don't you call IEnumSpObjectTokens::GetCount before even trying to retrieve any tokens. ...

... Doing so will give you information of how many tokens is contained within the enumeration sequence first. You can actually use this information later in order to enumerate multiple tokens at once. Speaking of which IEnumSpObjectTokens::Next expects an array of tokens as its second parameter and not a single token object. If you have previously got the number of available tokens in enumeration sequence you can size this array appropriately.

I did a quick test of calling Category.SetId(SPCAT_VOICES, 1)... to no avail.
The single token enumeration was the suggestion made by Bing; it didn't seem too egregious due to the fact that there are only a few voices installed on most computers, and since it is only enumerating one at a time, the second parameter is declared as a single token (a one-element array :)

Old SAPI and OneCore should have very similar interfaces, so old examples should work after small modifications: http://blog.blong.com/2021/04/sapi-microsoft-speech-api-problems-with.html

Microsoft stopped development on SAPI a long time ago.   More recent development has focused on OneCore/WinRT APIs (e.g. System.Speech.Synthesis), and Microsoft Mark is a WinRT voice, not a SAPI voice.   You would need to update your code to use System.Speech.Synthesis instead of SAPI.
